# Get request out of onResponse

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have a method that does a GET request using Volley Library

```
public void get(String url) {

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println("Successfull response is: " + response);
                }
            }, createMyReqErrorListener()) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put(ACCEPT, ACCEPT_JSON);
            headers.put(AUTH_ID, AUTH_ID_VALUE);
            headers.put(PLATFORM, PLATFORM_VALUE);
            headers.put(CID, "");
            System.out.println(headers.toString());
            return headers;

        }
    };

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

In the onResponse Override method i would like to get the response object passed onto my parser which is in a data class, which will then pass the parsed info (images/name etc) to the activity so it can display it?

How could i pass the object up the chain?

Comment: post your json response. and for parsing you can use gson.

Comment: Sorry, its a bit early what you mean post my response?

Comment: the value you are getting in this method `response`.   `onResponse(String response)`